# Keep an eye on someone or something

Tags: sentence-usage

Please imagine you want to alarm someone about a dangerous dog; you can say:

> - Keep an eye on that dog.

Or when you as an agent are taking a prisoner from a jail to prison. You want to go to the toilette for a minute and you outsource your duty to your co-worker while you're away. You would probably say something like:

> - Keep an eye on the prisoner.

But is it possible for a mother to ask her kids father to take care of their kids while she is going to do something for a short period of the time (e.g. 10 minutes)? I mean:

> - Keep an eye on the kids.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you are using the word **alarm** incorrectly in the first line of your question. If you want to frighten somebody, this is the correct word. If you want to advise somebody about a potential problem, the words **alert** or **warn** would be better.

Comment: Yes @JavaLatte. Agreed. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely, the idiom

> keep an eye on
>   keep an eye on = look after

can be used for looking after children and other things.

> Sorry I can't meet for a coffee, I need to **keep an eye on** the kids.
>   She asked her husband to **keep an eye on** the kids when she was at work on the weekend.
>
> I can't leave at the moment, I need to **keep an eye on** this turkey for Thanksgiving dinner.

In your dog example, if the watcher can currently see the dog, then

> Keep an eye **on** the dog.

is correct.  If, however, the watcher needs to keep looking for the dog and can not currently see it, then

> Keep an eye **out for** the dog.

is appropriate.